# Burning a Custom CD/DVD software Image

Tags: windows, images, iso-image

Hello I am trying to Burn a disk let me catch you up where I am at as I have a very SPECIFIC question and it may be difficult to explain but I will try to keep it simple:

I have software already in an ISO file; I am using Daemon tools on a Windows based PC

What I am wanting to do is create the actual Picture (not disk image file) that will show up on the Disk drive when I insert the disk

Eg: if you put microsoft Office 11 in your comp. you open up My Computer to view all your HD and Disk drives you will see the image that microsoft put on the disk which is a silver CD and the Microsoft Office logo on the top corner.

I would like to know how to edit my current ISO file or what I need to do in order to put "A PICTURE" or "AN ICON FILE" on the CD/DVD so that when I insert the disk into any PC it will show up with the PICTURE OR ICON file I chose and look proffessional.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an icon file - .ico format and an autorun.inf file that points to the icon file in the root of the ISO.

The autorun.inf file is just a text file.  It's contents would look like:

```
[autorun]
icon=picture.ico
```

The autorun.inf is also what determines if a CD runs a program when it is inserted - hence the name autorun.

See this for more details:  http://dailycupoftech.com/usb-drive-autoruninf-tweaking/